# I cannot get a tutorial to work adapted to my application. How I can map a general URL to HTTP methods of an API endpoint written in C#?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I am not able to receive and display results from a C# Web API using Typescript and Angular. I am new to Typescript.

I have written a service in Typescript based on this tutorial: [https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2016/02/01/consuming-a-rest-api-with-angular-http-service-in-typescript/][1]

I consume the service in a module Categories.

But I can not get the response so that I can display it as table on the Categories page.

In environments.ts I have the following configuration according to the URL:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  server: 'http://localhost:5001/',
  apiUrl: 'api/',
};
```

In the service I have for example a get method:

```
getAll<T>(): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(this.actionUrl);
  }
```

`this.actionUrl` is constructed using the variables from the environment (server and apiUrl).

On Server side I have a method GetCategory in my Web-API I want to call.

CategoriesController.cs

```
// GET: api/Categories
        [HttpGet(Name = nameof(GetCategory))]
        public string GetCategory()
        {
            var list = _context.Category.ToList();

            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(list);
            return json;
        }
```

So when I run it in my browser there is the following error message:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE                         :5001/api/:1

In the console of the Edge browser there is:
GET http://localhost:5001/api/
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

My categories page is empty.

When I type the URL from my Web-API into my browser (https://localhost:5001/api/Categories/)  then I can receive the JSON directly into my browser.

So how I can map the URL so that It can work  based on the tutorial I tried ?

I am using .NET Core 3.1 ; C#,  TypeScript; Angular CLI 8.3.26; Angular web template in Visual Studio Community 2019
[1]: https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2016/02/01/consuming-a-rest-api-with-angular-http-service-in-typescript/

Comment: Change URL from http to https.  You link is from 2016 which is old and most server need to do authentication with TLS for https communications.  You loaded a new version of angular that probably need the secure https.

Comment: When I change the URL to https I reveice "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" when I am trying to consume my C# webservice.

Comment: The code is working with the browser so the same URL should be used in the tutorial.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the Working Browser and c#.  First check the TLS version to see if they match.Then compare the headers in then first request.The default headers are different in c# and a Browser.I suspect Angular is using the default TLS version of machine and is probably using the old TLS 1.0/1.1 which will not work.  You will need to set the default TLS version with following : System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Answer (score 0):

It can be a number of things, but I remember having some troubles setting my environment so start by checking your JSON serialization parameters in your API.

I use Newtonsoft as I didn't have much success with the default JSON serializer, honestly I wasted a lot of time trying to get it to work with my angular app so I gave up and Newtonsoft worked pretty much right away.

Here's what I have for my working API :

In Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices

Ignore the options.Filters.Add(typeof(AuthorizationFilter)); as it does not apply to you

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(typeof(AuthorizationFilter));
            })
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(x => {
                x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                x.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
            });

services.AddMvc(options => options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("json", "text/html"))
                    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest);
```

If that doesn't help, I would then subscribe to that getAll observable of yours and console log to see what's in there.
Make sure your properties in your angular model matches the ones in your Asp.net API model.

Comment: AddNewtonsoftJson can not be found.

Comment: You have to download the nuget package if you were not using it : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: I installed Newtonsoft.Json and used using Newtonsoft.Json and the method still does not exist (IMvcBuilder does not contain a definition for AddNewtonsoftJson).

Comment: Here's the exact package I use : <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.4" />

Comment: Also make sure you have the required using statements.. using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;